# Insert random integer from java to mysql as unique ID

Tags: java, mysql

How do I insert a generated random integer from java and insert into MySQL as unique id?

Comment: Can you mention what you tried till now? Or giving homework for us.

Answer (score 0):

generate random number

```
Random rand = new Random();
int x = rand.nextInt(100000);
```

before storing to database you have to check that number is already stored or not.
after checking that you can insert.

why do you insert random number as a unique id?.you can auto increment your primary key.then you can easily insert unique number for you primary key.and no need to create random number.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it inverse: use an AUTOINCREMENT primary key on the table and per JDBC do not insert that primary key, but afterwards query the key generated by MySQL, concurrency safe.

```
try (PreparedStatement stm = conn.prepareStatement(
        "INSERT INTO moviesTbl  (title, ...) VALUES(?, ? ...)")) {
    stm.setString(1, title);
    stm.setString(2, ...);
    ...
    int updateCount = stm.executeUpdate();
    if (updateCount != 0) {
        try (ResultSet genKeys = stm.getGeneratedKeys()) {
            if (genKeys.next()) { // At most 1 record inserted
                // Normally only one key generated per record.
                int generatedId = genKeys.getInt(0);
                ...
            }
        } // Close result set.
    }
} // Closes stm
```

JDBC returns a ResultSet as you could have inserted several records. And then you could have several generated keys per record.

---

Storing a UUID has not a full support in MySQL; maybe that the JDBC driver has support already.
A UUID is a 128 bit number, MaySQL BINARY(16), or CHAR(36) with something like [this](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,49626,172029#msg-172029)

```
CREATE FUNCTION `BINTOUUID`(UUID BINARY(16)) RETURNS char(36) 
BEGIN 
RETURN concat(HEX(LEFT(uuid,4)),'-', HEX(MID(uuid,5,2)),'-', HEX(MID(uuid,7,2)),
    '-',HEX(MID(uuid,9,2)),'-',HEX(RIGHT(uuid,6))); 
END
```

As I think you do not mean this, I leave it at that.